# Вводные слова ТОЧНЕЕ, А ТОЧНЕЕ в качестве союзов

Tags: вводные

У Лопатина на эту тему приводятся такие примеры: Приду вечером, точнее в девять часов. Отчет о том, каких высот, а точнее глубин удалось добиться в познании природы. Можно также предположить: Вечером, точнее в девять часов, буду у Вас.

Здесь явно просматриваются две темы:  а) сужение значения при уточнении с обособлением; б) подбор более точного по значению слова с разделением запятой.

И вот какие вопросы возникают:
1) Как теоретически объяснить разную пунктуацию при оформлении сходных выражений в правилах?
2) Почему в текстах встречаются самые разнообразные варианты?

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1) Над самым высоким местом подвески, а точнее над трехсотметровой пропастью со скалами на дне, они повисли. Не было ли у кого желания заняться водными видами спорта, а точнее серфингом? Стихи я писал всегда, а точнее, с пяти лет.

(2) Вот так наша затея с треском, а точнее с грохотом, провалилась.
Цветков, а точнее, соцветий на концах ветвей этих растений так много  Тебя, конечно, больше интересует качество, а точнее его соотношение с ценой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здесь просматриваются два вопроса:

1.Сосуществование **старого и нового правила**, разница между которыми основана на разном понимании уточняющего оборота.

2.Разница между **вводным словом и союзом**.

**1.**Согласно старому правилу вводные слова *вернее, точнее* особенные, они выделяются запятыми сами по себе: *Приду вечером, точнее, в девять часов и все расскажу.*

Объяснение: "Трудность, связанная с обособлением этих вводных слов, состоит в том, что они придают части предложения, следующей за ними, уточняющий характер. А потому у пишущего возникает желание обособить слова после вводного как уточняющий оборот.
Однако часть предложения, следующую за словами *вернее, скорее, точнее,* нельзя рассматривать как уточнение в силу специфического значения, которое добавляют в предложение эти вводные слова. Говорящий не хочет уточнить свое высказывание, он не идет от общего к частному, как это бывает при уточняющих конструкциях, например: *вечером, часов в шесть; в комнате, около тумбочки* и т.д. Используя вводные слова *вернее, скорее, точнее,* говорящий показывает, что он только что ошибся, неточно назвав нечто (предмет, действие и т.д.), и хочет исправить свою ошибку, назвав это нечто по-другому. Таким образом, в подобных предложениях говорящий описывает объект не в категории «целое - часть», а дает два равноправных названия одного и того же, просто второе точнее.
Члены предложения, следующие за этими вводными словами, следует рассматривать **не как уточняющую конструкцию, а как однородные** к членам предложения, стоящим до вводного: *Копань оказалась маленькой усадьбой, вернее, заброшенным хутором.*

Часто вводные слова *вернее, скорее, точнее* идут после сочинительного союза *или*, соединяющего однородные члены предложения или предложения, что еще раз подтверждает, что перед нами однородные члены предложения, а не уточняющая конструкция: *Затем появился моряк или, вернее, курсант*".

Согласно Лопатину уточняющий оборот есть, *вернее, точнее, скорее* уравнены в правах с другими вводными и по правилу не отделяются запятой от обособленного оборота: *Приду вечером, точнее в девять часов, и все расскажу.*

**2.**Согласно Розенталю *а вернее, а точнее, а скорее* - это вводные словосочетания, выделяются запятыми: *Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, а вернее, с живота на спину и думаю.*

Согласно Лопатину это союзы и вторая запятая не ставится: *Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, а вернее с живота на спину и думаю.* Причем «а скорее» – союз даже при противопоставлении: *Его не испугал, а скорее обрадовал этот вопрос.*

Приведенные в вопросе примеры, в которых *а точнее* оказывается в начале обособленного оборота и не отделяется от него запятой, - результат смешения правил в голове редактора. По старому правилу должно быть: *Вот так наша затея с треском, а точнее, с грохотом провалилась.* По новому: *Вот так наша затея с треском, а точнее с грохотом провалилась.*

Comment: Тат, а каким правилам теперь верить? Вообще в академическом справочнике новые правила не достаточно четко сформулированы, и это уже не раз обсуждалось. Эти правила еще, насколько мне известно, официально не утверждены. Но меня интересует другое. Как быть, например, с такими случаями, как например, привела София? Будет ли считаться ошибкой это?

Comment: Ошибками будут считаться примеры, не соответствующие ни старому, ни новому правилу: "Над самым высоким местом подвески, а точнее над трехсотметровой пропастью со скалами на дне, они повисли". "Вот так наша затея с треском, а точнее с грохотом, провалилась". Также будет странно, если в одном тексте применять и старое, и новое правило.

Comment: Вообще, как показывает мой опыт работы с печатными изданиями, большинство ориентируется на правила, сформулированные Розенталем. Некоторые академические корректировки ПАСа вошли в практику и даже внесены в современные издания Розенталя (например, "чем... тем" уже признан двойным союзом, тогда как у Розенталя перед "чем" стояла запятая). Но союзы "а точнее, а вернее, а скорее, а значит", хоть и вошли в словари служебных слов, до сих пор не признаются практиками и остаются вводными словосочетаниями.

Comment: Эта тема, изложенная у Лопатина, мне нравится больше, она может иметь грамматическое обоснование. (1) Если это СУЖЕНИЕ ПОНЯТИЯ,то вводное слово на правах союза по общему правилу относится к обособленному уточняющему члену: "Вечером, точнее в девять часов, буду у Вас". (2) Если это ПОДБОР БОЛЕЕ ТОЧНОГО СЛОВА, то в современной вузовской грамматике есть подходящая для этого тема, а именно ДИФФЕРЕНЦИРУЮЩИЕ союзы при ОДНОРОДНЫХ членах, в роли которых    могут выступать наречия, частицы, модальные и вводные слова.

Comment: Например: "Вообще его любили, ХОТЯ И почитали гордым". "Он сказал это простым, ДАЖЕ обыденным тоном". Тогда правильно будет: "Вот так наша затея с треском, А ТОЧНЕЕ с грохотом провалилась". Здесь однородные члены разделяются запятой, а в качестве дифференцирующего (уточняющего) союза выступает вводное слово А ТОЧНЕЕ.

Comment: София, а если так: Вечером, А ТОЧНЕЕ в девять часов буду у Вас? По Лопатину вторая запятая не нужна. Или у него есть что-то о союзе ТОЧНЕЕ. По-моему, у него все союзы начинаются с А. "А ТОЧНЕЕ" - союз, а "ТОЧНЕЕ" - нет.

Answer (score 2):

София, в правилах четко сказано: Вводные слова не отделяются от обособленного оборота, если даже занимают самое начало или самый конец предложения, например: ***По-видимому опасаясь осложнений, врач предложил больному соблюдать постельный режим***.

Над самым высоким местом подвески, ***а точнее над трехсотметровой пропастью со скалами на дне***.

Но все бы хорошо, если опять не разнобой. В правилах сказано: П р и м е ч а н и е 8. *Вводные слова точнее, вернее, скорее и т. п. не открывают собой обособленный оборот, поэтому они сами выделяются запятыми, например*: В лаборатории физики я впервые узнал, **вернее,** наглядно увидел, что такое последовательное и что такое параллельное соединение.
В сборнике подробно рассматриваются грамматические, ***точнее,*** синтаксические проблемы.
Получается, если верить правилам 1956 г., то в приведенных вами примерах после "точнее" запятая все же нужна. ***(Трудные случаи пунктуации). К. И. БЫЛИНСКИЙ, Д. Э. РОЗЕНТАЛЬ.***

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за ответ. Давайте пользоваться правилами Лопатина: они более логичны, их можно объяснить и вписать в общую систему. Важно, что они соответствуют предложениям с союзом ИЛИ, где также обозначена ОДНОРОДНОСТЬ членов при поборе нужного слова: "Небо на картине было ярко-голубое или, точнее сказать, бирюзовое". Но: "Постоялый двор, или, по-тамошнему, умёт, находился в стороне". Здесь обособление пояснительного члена со значением лексического тождества.

Comment: София, в некоторых примерах действительно, лучше применять новые правила. Как например, в этом: "Небо на картине было ярко-голубое или, точнее сказать, бирюзовое". По старым правилам здесь " точнее" надо было обособить. Но здесь вводное слово относится к обособленному уточняющему обороту и тесно с ним связан. Трудно представить обособленность "точнее". Так что, думаю, оба правила (новые и старые) хорошие, но все зависит от того или иного случая.