# Даже, точнее, точнее даже

Tags: пунктуация

1)Возьмем предложение: Карандаш был темно-синим, даже черным. - Здесь "даже черным" - присоединительная конструкция. Пример был придуман на основе предложения "Был тепло, даже жарко." (хотя если переделать его так: Был теплый и даже жаркий день. - Как тогда расставить запятые? Чем тогда будет являться (и)даже?

2) Переделаем: Карандаш был темно-синим или, точнее(говоря), черным.  Здесь союз "или" является разделительным, "точнее(говоря)" - вводное слово. Без "или" это употребительно? - Карандаш был темно-синим, точнее() черным.

3) Употребим "даже" и "точнее" вместе: Карандаш был темно-синим, точнее даже черным. - Здесь "точнее даже черным" - присоединительная конструкция, а "точнее" просто служит каким-нибудь усилением? Или же так: Карандаш был темно-синим, точнее, даже черным. - Где "точнее" - вводное слово?

Я читал правила на слово "Даже", на слова "скорее, точнее, вернее", правила употребления вводных слов, правила, разграничивающие "пояснительные, уточняющие, и присоединительные конструкции". Еще я смотрел вот эту тему [rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41320/Вводные-слова-ТОЧНЕЕ-А-ТОЧНЕЕ-в-качестве-союзов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41320/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%95-%D0%90-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%95-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2)
ну и о союзных аналогах читал немного - но там вообще муть.

Answer (score 1):

> Карандаш был темно-синим, даже черным.

Здесь "даже" союз.

> Был теплый и даже жаркий день

А здесь - усилительная частица.

Смысла нагромождения горы примеров в вашем вопросе я не понял. 
Как ни крути, а разница между союзом и частицей вполне очевидна.
Союз соединает две части, частица относится только к одному слову (или словосочетанию - крайне редко).
Вы можете четко сформулировать, что именно Вы хотите спросить?

Comment: Я запутался в уточняющих, пояснительных и присоединительных конструкциях. Просто есть много различных правил, и они могут дополнять или противоречить друг другу.

Comment: Если вводное слово «точнее» находится в составе присоединительного оборота, то никакими знаками препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: Я увидел, точнее почувствовал, что она ко мне неравнодушна. - Почему это присоединительная, а не уточняющая конструкция?

Comment: В некоторых источниках указывается, что вводные слова вернее, точнее, придающие высказыванию уточняющий характер, выделяются запятыми, при этом следующие за ними члены предложения не обособляются. Такое пунктуационное оформление, действительно, возможно: Но тебе, мальчик, вернее, твоему имени я кое-чем обязан.

Comment: Однако в примерах из художественной литературы часто встречается иная расстановка знаков препинания: уточняющие члены предложения, вводимые словами вернее, точнее, обособляются, а сами эти слова, стоящие в начале обособленного оборота, в соответствии с общим правилом не отделяются от него запятой (но иногда могут быть отделены тире): К сожалению, врачи еще мало умеют распознавать истерическую, вернее психическую, природу ряда заболеваний.

Comment: Союз + вводное слово. То же, что «а точнее говоря, а правильнее сказать». Если слово «точнее» можно изъять или переместить, то оно выделяется с двух сторон знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Если же исключить или переставить слово «точнее» нельзя, то запятая между «а» и «точнее» не ставится.
Но я не понимал, в чем дело, и только продолжал жалко бубнить, что мой ящик – это не совсем ящик, а точнее, совсем не ящик. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Сказка о тройке. Он не шёл, а, точнее, бежал, боясь опоздать на поезд.

Comment: Его не испугал этот вопрос, а скорее обрадовал – без запятой после слова скорее, которое здесь не уточняет предыдущее высказывание, а усиливает противопоставление

Comment: Если после союза или следуют вводные слова вернее, точнее, скорее (по значению равные сочетаниям «вернее говоря», «точнее говоря» и т.п.), а также вводное сочетание лучше сказать, то союз или является разделительным, а не пояснительным, поэтому запятыми выделяются только эти вводные слова и сочетания. Трудно или, лучше сказать, скучно потому, что это была работа дробная, мелкая (Белинский); Двойная или, точнее, тройная доза лекарства оказала свое действие на больного; Всех удивило его замечание или, скорее, тон этого замечания.

Comment: СКОРЕЕ, вводное слово
То же, что «вернее, точнее сказать».А я, скорее, даже – пострадавший.

ТОЧНЕЕ ГОВОРЯ / СКАЗАТЬ, вводное выражение и члены предложения

1. Вводное выражение. То же, что «вернее, лучше сказать» ...уставших от нашей европейской, точнее сказать, парижской цивилизации, милой, но к упадку клонящейся. Ф. Сологуб, Звериный быт.

Comment: Розенталь обособляет слова ''вернее'', ''точнее'', ''скорее''. Но если вводное слово находится в начале  присоединительного оборота( уточнение, пояснение, присоединение), то никакими знаками препинания от оборота оно не отделяется.

Comment: Лопатин же считает, что вводные слова ''вернее'', ''точнее'', ''скорее'' придают уточняющий характер и не отделяются от уточняющего члена предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, что "Был теплый и даже жаркий день" – очень сомнительная конструкция.
От этого и все трудности. Союз "И" совсем ни к чему.

> Карандаш был темно-синим, даже черным. Здесь "даже" союз (*behemothus*).

Отнюдь. Кузнецов считает частицей. Именно усилительной. Ничем не отличается от *Было тепло, даже жарко*.

Comment: А сразу за этой фразой пишет, что союз.

Answer (score 0):

1. Никто никогда не скажет: ‟Был теплый и даже жаркий день”, так как после слова ‟теплый” говорящий делает паузу и корректирует ответ в присоединительной конструкции.  Если человек не делает паузу перед ‟или”, то он изначально так и задумывал предложение, а не скорректировал его в процессе произношения с помощью присоединительной конструкции. Вместо ‟и” здесь подходит ничего или ‟или”. **В итоге: ‟Был теплый, или даже жаркий, день” или ‟Был теплый, даже жаркий, день”.**
2. Тут та же ошибка. Если человек передумывает или корректирует ответ, то он делает паузу перед ‟или” в такого рода предложениях. **Итог: ‟ Карандаш был темно-синим, или, точнее, черным.”**

Answer (score -1):

В примере **"Был теплый и даже жаркий день"**  даже - усилительная частица при союзе и, который соединяет однородные члены предложения: теплый и жаркий день. Запятая не нужна.

Употребление разделительного союза при словах **"точнее","вернее"** не обязательно. **Карандаш был темно-синим, точнее(,) черным.** Запятая ставится по старым правилам. Согласно Академическому справочнику запятая ставится только перед этими словами, которые не отделяются от уточняющего члена предложения.

В примере **"Карандаш был темно-синим, точнее(,) даже черным"** запятая ставится по старым правилам,  в соответствие же с  Академическим справочником запятая не нужна.

В значение же союза эти слова выступают только в сочетании с **а**.

Ср.: Приду вечером, точнее в девять часов — **вводное слово при уточнении;** Приеду осенью, а точнее в октябре — **союзное сочетание;**

См.: [ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С УТОЧНЯЮЩИМИ ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ И ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm#%D0%B7_01)

Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
М.: ЧеРо, 1999

[Знаки препинания при уточняющих, пояснительных и присоединительных членах предложения](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)

Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Возьмем такой пример: Было тепло, даже жарко. - Здесь присоединительная конструкция. Переделаем: Было тепло, скорее даже жарко. - Добавили скорее. Это все еще присоединительная конструкция? Тогда чем будет скорее и какую роль оно здесь играет? Вводное слово? Оно не отделяется запятой, потому что есть правило, что вводные слова, стоящие в начале или в конце обособленных оборотов не отделяются от них запятой?

Comment: Здесь вводное слово в составе присоединительного оборота, запятая не ставится.

Comment: Я сейчас поздравлял человека с днем рождения, там были такие слова: "...желаю тебе всего самого наилучшего, а точнее того самого наилучшего". Я не пойму, здесь мы уточняем или поясняем. Или это однородные определения?

Comment: Фраза не совсем понятна.  Одно и то же повторяется.

Comment: Смотрите, так по Розенталю: Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, вернее, с живота на спину и думаю… Так по Лопатину: Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, вернее с живота на спину и думаю… Всё верно?

Comment: Вы не внимательно читаете. Вводные слова ( согласно Розенталю) придающие высказыванию уточняющий характер, выделяются запятыми. Те же вводные слова ( согласно Академическому справочнику) ***не отделяются от уточняющего члена предложения***.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы!

Comment: А еще я нашел такой пример: Однако в примерах из художественной литературы часто встречается иная расстановка знаков препинания: уточняющие члены предложения, вводимые словами вернее, точнее, обособляются, а сами эти слова, стоящие в начале обособленного оборота, в соответствии с общим правилом не отделяются от него запятой (но иногда могут быть отделены тире): К сожалению, врачи еще мало умеют распознавать истерическую, вернее психическую, природу ряда заболеваний.

Comment: Т.е получается: Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, вернее с живота на спину, и думаю…

Comment: А мой пример из поздравления выше переделаю: Желаю тебе всего наилучшего, а точнее всего Самого наилучшего. Желаю тебе счастья, а точнее душевного благополучия. Не пойму: здесь мы уточняем, поясняем или же это однородные члены?

Comment: В примере "Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, вернее с живота на спину, и думаю'' запятая, конечно ставится после ''спину'', т.к. ''и думаю'' не входит в уточняющий оборот.

Comment: В примере  ''Желаю тебе счастья, а точнее душевного благополучия"  запятая не нужна. Вводное слово стоит в начале присоединительного оборота ( По Розенталю), а по Лопатину ''а точнее ''союзное сочетание''.

Comment: Но почему этот оборот присоединительный, а не уточняющий или пояснительный?

Comment: В примере "Переворачиваюсь с боку на бок, вернее с живота на спину, и думаю'' запятая, конечно ставится после ''спину'', т.к. ''и думаю'' не входит в уточняющий оборот. – Серж


Отчет о том, каких высот, а точнее глубин удалось добиться в познании природы... - Пример из Лопатина, "удалось добиться" тоже не входит в уточняющий оборот, но запятой не отделяется

Comment: Присоединительный оборот ( по Розенталю) включает в себя: уточнение, пояснение, присоединение.  На мой взгляд, это пояснение.

Comment: В примере из справочника Лопатина  запятая не ставится, потому что ''а точнее''  - союзное сочетание.