# Обособление "точнее"; не "как правильно?", а как лучше смотрится?

Tags: вводные-слова

Здесь был (и есть) вопрос:

**[Вводные слова ТОЧНЕЕ, А ТОЧНЕЕ в качестве союзов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41320/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%95-%D0%90-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%95-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

Ответы: по Розенталю так, по Лопатину этак.

> История фонтана, ставшего всемирно известным благодаря кинофильму “La
>   Dolce Vita”, точнее сцене ночного купания в исполнении Аниты Экберг и
>   Марчелло Мастроянни, началась задолго до победы неореализма.

Меня смущает пустота после "точнее", но и запятую ставить перо не поднимается...

Как же ж жить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая в данном случае **не ставится:**

**Уточняющие** члены предложения могут иметь  вводные слова ТОЧНЕЕ,  А ТОЧНЕЕ в качестве **присоединительных союзов** (как и другие вводные слова).

Примеры:

Вечером, точнее в девять часов, буду у вас. 
Осенью, а точнее в октябре, состоится учредительный съезд.
Стихи я писал всегда, а точнее с пяти лет. Эта весть изрядно обрадовала жителей юга США, а точнее его прибрежной части.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Другой вариант для вводных слов ТОЧНЕЕ, А ТОЧНЕЕ – это  подбор нужного слова. В этом случае мы имеем **ОДНОРОДНУЮ** связь, при этом ТОЧНЕЕ, А ТОЧНЕЕ являются дифференцирующими союзами (нет обособления):

Он переутомился, а вернее болен. Отчет о том, каких высот, а точнее глубин удалось добиться в познании природы. Вот так наша затея с треском, а точнее с грохотом провалилась. Цветков, а точнее соцветий на концах ветвей этих растений очень  много.

**Но у  Розенталя**:  Его доброта, **вернее**, его великодушие тронуло меня.

Он не различал варианты с уточнением и однородными отношениями, поэтому считал, что надо обособить ТОЧНЕЕ.