# Запятая при вводном слове

Tags: пунктуация

1. **Они рассказали нам, по каким дорогам, вернее, направлениям(,) лучше ехать. Дорог как таковых там нет.**
2. **Вы прекрасно знаете, где я состою, а я состою в группе Искоренения, и поэтому ваш вопрос, а вернее, контрвопрос(,) абсолютно лишен смысла.**

Почему в этих примерах не ставится запятая? Из-за наличия вводного слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не просто вводное слово, а некий оборот, требующий обособления (после чего мы и будем называть его не "неким", а обособленным).

Цитирую **[правило](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)**:

> Если вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота – запятые
>   ставятся перед вводным словом и после всего обособленного оборота.
>   После вводного слова запятая не ставится (иначе говоря, запятая,
>   которая должна была «закрывать» вводное слово, переносится в конец
>   обособленного оборота).

Запятая в Ваших раз-два ставится, но не там где стоит, а где робко притулилась в скобочках.

1. *Они рассказали нам, по каким дорогам, вернее направлениям, лучше ехать. Дорог как таковых там нет.*
2. *Вы прекрасно знаете, где я состою, а я состою в группе Искоренения, и поэтому ваш вопрос, а вернее контрвопрос, абсолютно лишен смысла.*

   ---

См. [другие **ответы**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431358/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F) (вторая строка в моём вопросе тоже приведёт Вас к ответам об обособлении вводных).

Comment: Спасибо,примеры взяты с сайтов по русскому языку.Отсюда и непонимание.