# Запятые при "точнее"

Tags: запятые

Дано предложение:

> Точнее(,) глухой(,) очень отдалённый(,) взрыв.

Почитала [вот тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41320/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%95-%D0%90-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%95-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2), но всё равно не поняла, как расставить запятые?
Я склоняюсь ко второй и третьей запятой: *Точнее глухой, очень отдалённый, взрыв.* Подскажите, пожалуйста, так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял смысл, надо так:

> Точнее, глухой, очень отдалённый взрыв.

*"Очень отдалённый",* насколько я понимаю, не уточняет слово *"глухой",* поэтому последняя запятая не нужна. Это просто однородные члены, разделённые запятой.

*"Точнее"* у вас, по всей видимости, вводное слово со смыслом *точнее сказать.* В противном случае смысл должен быть такой: "*Более точным является* глухой, очень отдалённый взрыв", но вы явно не это имели в виду. Если б ещё выстрел был вместо взрыва, тогда я ещё понимаю. В таком случае после *"точно"* запятая бы не требовалась.

Comment: Ага, поняла логику. Спасибо, разобралась.